# Can't run script function inside Github Workflow

Tags: bash, github-actions

I am running this particular workflow ----------------

```
    - name: Generating Release
      run: |
          echo '#!/bin/sh
            set -e

            do_hash() {
                HASH_NAME=$1
                HASH_CMD=$2
                echo "${HASH_NAME}:"
                for f in $(find -type f); do
                    f=$(echo $f | cut -c3-) # remove ./ prefix
                    if [ "$f" = "Release" ]; then
                        continue
                    fi
                    echo " $(${HASH_CMD} ${f}  | cut -d" " -f1) $(wc -c $f)"
                done
            }

            cat << EOF
            Origin: Example Repository
            Label: Example
            Suite: stable
            Codename: stable
            Version: 1.0
            Architectures: amd64 arm64 arm7
            Components: main
            Description: An example software repository
            Date: $(date -Ru)
            EOF
            do_hash "MD5Sum" "md5sum"
            do_hash "SHA1" "sha1sum"
            do_hash "SHA256" "sha256sum"
            ' > example/generate-release.sh

    - name: Run bash script
      shell: bash
      run: |
          chmod +x example/generate-release.sh
          example/generate-release.sh > example/apt-repo/dists/stable/Release
```

What I expect to see: (As it works fine locally)

```
Origin: Example Repository
Label: Example
Suite: stable
Codename: stable
Version: 1.0
Architectures: amd64 arm64 arm7
Components: main
Description: An example software repository
Date: Thu, 30 Jun 2022 10:15:35 +0000
MD5Sum:
 24ad62d0dd8b8db40835806e6c1cfba0 313 main/binary-all/Packages.gz
 3f262d7bae8d6c3ce62412c94feccac4 402 main/binary-all/Packages
SHA1:
 c33a36724286880a90048c31c33bd391175bc7c1 313 main/binary-all/Packages.gz
 1c227b077a8670f9af5ec49b8c915ad37d83955e 402 main/binary-all/Packages
SHA256:
 4915c7f84fe865a912a4179f1a212af678ebe6556580d2d86fce7e7d1eba190e 313 main/binary-all/Packages.gz
 3c367007ed6410bb17a36ceaf28350e4563e8f1f8f5d244213b6cc967eec7464 402 main/binary-all/Packages
```

Workflow does not give me any error - But, I am getting :

```
  Origin: Example Repository
  Label: Example
  Suite: stable
  Codename: stable
  Version: 1.0
  Architectures: amd64 arm64 arm7
  Components: main
  Description: An example software repository
  Date: Fri, 01 Jul 2022 12:52:14 +0000
  EOF
  do_hash "MD5Sum" "md5sum"
  do_hash "SHA1" "sha1sum"
  do_hash "SHA256" "sha256sum"
```

How should I instruct github workflow to use do_hash as a function ?!

Comment: You have your script wrapped in a `echo` so it prints the script instead of execute it.

Comment: I recommend checking out [bash pitfall 1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Comment: @jordanm right, echo command is just printing out and saving the content to sh file. But, in the next step the script should execute, + If the issue was a bash pitfall, it would  not have worked in the local system as well ! I suspect that somehow Github actions is executing things differently !